# large text as a parameter to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function with 3 input params like `test(p1, p2, p3)`. Params `p1` and `p2` are numeric, and param `p3` is a string.

Everything seems to work as expected until I provide a string containg approximately 100 chars or more along with special characters. Once I do so, the function throws an error. Here is an example value I have tried for `p3`:

> "hi this is a text parameter having special characters like # ,. ,_......"

How can I pass a parameter containging 100+ characters including special characters to the JavaScript function?

Comment: A string with 100 characters isn't large. There's no example of an issue here. Post actual, verified code with the real error messages you're getting.

Comment: Please post example code that can run and demonstrate your issue along with the specific error message you are getting.

Comment: What is the content of the text? It probably has some characters that needs escaping

Comment: ex:  html+=` '<sometags ng-click='+test(p1,p2,p3)+'/>'; like this

Comment: You need handle the special characters before pass as the parameter

Comment: but handling special char is not an issue my issue is had to pass  a large user input text as  a  parameter to the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this - store it in field in html by the function that generates this variable (can be a hidden field), then retrieve it using either jQuery or document.getElementById, for example if this is my hidden field:

```
<input id="myLongStringStore" name="prodId" type="hidden" value="">
```

and this is the function which generates the long string:

```
function myFunction ()
{
   var myString = "sahj&^%fasd^$)jlk()*/£fgh";
   var myHiddenInput = document.getElementById("myLongStringStore");
   myHiddenInput.innerHTML = myString; // or .value = myString;
}
```

Then in your function keep the first two parameters and then obtain the long string from the hidden input:

```
function test(p1,p2)
{
  var p3 = document.getElementById("myLongStringStore").innerHTML; // or 
                                                               // .value

  // you can also do this in jQuery:
  var p3 = $('#myLongStringStore');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: note that you might have to insert escape characters into your string

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion .I  resolved  my problem by adding "&quot;" in the begning  and end  instead of "'"and this solves my  problem.